pycharm не дает загрузить проект на git-hub
решил задеплоить проект на гитхаб, вошел в аккаунт в пайчарме, но при попытке загрузить проект получаю вот такую ошибку

сталкивался ли кто с такой ошибкой? как решать? pycharm community edition

Попробуйте удалить remote и добавить его заново, но через консоль: git remote add origin https://github.com/...., не забудьте про протокол, он тоже важен
